# How to integrate i18next in a app written with ionic-react in ionic version 7

Tags: ionic-react

I would like to integrate i18next in my ionic-react app. But I can’t cope with it. My ionic version is 7.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install packages

```
npm install i18next react-i18next
```

2. Create folders and translationfiles, for example

```
scr/translations/en/global.json
```

3. Fill the translationsfiles, for example

```
{
  "header": {
    "text": "Welcome",
    "text2": "Welcome2"
    }
}
```

4. In `index.tsx` or `main.tsx` import the translationsfiles and do imports and functions like this:

```
import global_en from "./translations/en/global.json";
import global_de from "./translations/de/global.json";
import i18next from "i18next";
import { I18nextProvider } from "react-i18next";

i18next.init({
  interpolation: { escapeValue: false },
  lng: "de",
  resources: {
    en: {
      global: global_en,
    },
    de: {
      global: global_de,
    },
  },
});
```

and in the EventListener do surroundings with

```
<I18nextProvider i18n={i18next}>
<App />
</I18nextProvider>
```

5. Now you can use your translations in other pages, for example in `App.tsx`

```
import { useTranslation, initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
```

and in the const App...

```
const [t, i18n] = useTranslation("global");

const handleChangeLanguage = (lang: string) => {
  i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
};

return...

<h1>{t('header.text')}</h1>
```